# Save files too large

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My save files are way too large!

I have been playing up to lv 15 with ~40 mods and before I knew the word of it my save file went up to ~700Mb in size.

Any way to reduce this? I tried to remove orphaned script instances with a save tool but only 670 out of 72K scripts were removed. Most likely my save file is simply too big.

Is there any way to make it smaller or to prevent the same from happening in the future?

Comment: I'd think it quite possible just one mod is eating up save size. It might take some time, but you could try individually disabling them, and making test saves off your main from there to see if any go back down to a reasonable size.

Comment: I disabled all mods and saved and now it went down to 8000Kb. I am going to enable the mods 1 by 1 after thoroughly checking the reviews and tests. I agree with the one mod bloat though.

Answer (score 3):

700 Mb sounds like there's an underlying issue causing a lot of bloat. Ensure that all your mods are well tested (read comments on the mod pages on the nexus) and that your [load order](https://loot.github.io/) is correct (LOOT also warns you about known issues with some mods). I tend to agree with user *Katana314* that some mod is causing a huge amount of bloat.

One thing you can try as a temporary solution is go to some indoor cell (your house, etc) and wait 10 or 30 ingame days (various things in the game have different [respawn timers](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Respawning)). This will essentially reset most cells in the game and can reduce your save size.

However, the size you describe is totally out of order, so you should definitely look among your mods for potential trouble makers (posting your load order with a question like this is never a bad thing).